# No se admite la referencia cultural C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2015

He estado teniendo problemas al querer instalar el programa publicado, siendo que al compilar y ejecutar directamente desde el Visual Studio 2015 funciona bien

aquí esta el error que me genera al momento de instalar el programa publicado

```
INFORMACIÓN DE VERSIÓN DE LA PLATAFORMA
    Windows             : 6.3.9600.0 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.42000
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    clr.dll             : 4.7.3130.0 built by: NET472REL1LAST_B
    dfdll.dll           : 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    dfshim.dll          : 6.3.9600.16384 (winblue_rtm.130821-1623)

ORÍGENES
    Dirección URL de la implementación          : file:///C:/Users/Modulo%202%20C2/Desktop/Nodo2%20NEW%20server%20c2/Prestamundo1.application
    Dirección URL de la aplicación          : file:///C:/Users/Modulo%202%20C2/Desktop/Nodo2%20NEW%20server%20c2/Application%20Files/Prestamundo1_1_0_0_101/Prestamundo1.exe.manifest

IDENTIDADES
    Identidad de la implementación      : Prestamundo1.application, Version=1.0.0.101, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil
    Identidad de la aplicación      : Prestamundo1.exe, Version=1.0.0.101, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil, type=win32

RESUMEN DE LA APLICACIÓN
    * Aplicación instalable.

RESUMEN DEL ERROR
    Abajo se muestra un resumen de los errores; los detalles de estos errores se incluyen en el registro.
    * La activación de C:\Users\Modulo 2 C2\Desktop\Nodo2 NEW server c2\Prestamundo1.application dio como resultado una excepción. Se detectaron los siguientes mensajes de error:
        + No se admite la referencia cultural.
Nombre del parámetro: name
aa-ER es un identificador de referencia cultural no válido.

RESUMEN DE ERRORES DE TRANSACCIÓN DEL ALMACÉN DE COMPONENTES
    No se detectó ningún error de transacción.

ADVERTENCIAS
    * El manifiesto para esta aplicación no tiene signatura. Se ignorará la validación de signatura.
    * El manifiesto para esta aplicación no tiene signatura. Se ignorará la validación de signatura.

ESTADO DE PROGRESO DE LA OPERACIÓN
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:36 p. m.] : Se ha iniciado la activación de C:\Users\Modulo 2 C2\Desktop\Nodo2 NEW server c2\Prestamundo1.application.
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:38 p. m.] : El procesamiento del manifiesto de la implementación finalizó correctamente.
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:38 p. m.] : Se ha iniciado la instalación de la aplicación.
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:38 p. m.] : Ha finalizado correctamente el procesamiento del manifiesto de la aplicación.
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:39 p. m.] : Se ha encontrado una versión del runtime compatible 4.0.30319.
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:39 p. m.] : Ha finalizado la solicitud de confianza y detección de plataforma.

DETALLES DEL ERROR
    Se detectaron los siguientes errores durante esta operación.
    * [22/07/2018 01:45:40 p. m.] System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException
        - No se admite la referencia cultural.
Nombre del parámetro: name
aa-ER es un identificador de referencia cultural no válido.
        - Origen: mscorlib
        - Seguimiento de la pila:
            en System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
            en System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.ConstructAssemblyName(IntPtr asmMetaPtr, Char[] asmNameBuf, UInt32 asmNameLength, IntPtr pubKeyPtr, UInt32 pubKeyBytes, UInt32 flags)
            en System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.ImportIdentity()
            en System.Deployment.Application.AssemblyMetaDataImport.get_Name()
            en System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromCompLibAssembly(String filePath)
            en System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest.LoadFromInternalManifestFile(String filePath)
            en System.Deployment.Application.Manifest.AssemblyManifest..ctor(String filePath)
            en System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.ProcessDownloadedFile(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            en System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.DownloadModifiedEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, DownloadEventArgs e)
            en System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.OnModified()
            en System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadSingleFile(DownloadQueueItem next)
            en System.Deployment.Application.SystemNetDownloader.DownloadAllFiles()
            en System.Deployment.Application.FileDownloader.Download(SubscriptionState subState, X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
            en System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDependencies(SubscriptionState subState, AssemblyManifest deployManifest, AssemblyManifest appManifest, Uri sourceUriBase, String targetDirectory, String group, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl, Uri& deploymentUri)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
--- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la ubicación anterior donde se produjo la excepción ---
            en System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivationWithRetry(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            en System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

DETALLES DE TRANSACCIÓN DEL ALMACÉN DE COMPONENTES
    No hay información disponible sobre la transacción.
```

Comment: El error es claro. `aa-ER` no es un identificador de cultura válido. Revisa donde estás haciendo referencia a esa cultura

Comment: si lo entiendo, pero en ningun lugar mando llamar esa cultura, el problema solo se presenta al instalar el programa ya publicado

Comment: Curiosamente, aa-ER si existe: `Afar (Eritrea):aa-ER`.

Comment: Vale,tras revisar un poco, `aa-ER` si que está soportado por .NET pero solo a partir de windows 10. Eso significa que si tu entorno de trabajo es windows 10 y donde intentas instalar la aplicación es anterior, puede darte ese error. Pero volviendo al principio, en algun lugar de tu app se hace referencia a esa cultura...

Comment: Se me acaba de ocurrir..fijate a ver si tienes algun archivo de recursos que sea algo como `.aa-ER.resx`. Si es así, eliminalo

Comment: si, estoy desarrollando el sistema en Windows 10, y si trato de instalar en una versión mas antigua


Y si efectivamente al buscar `resx` tenia un archivo con `aa-ER.resx`

Comment: Gracias @Pikoh ya compile, publique y dejo instalar, una vez borrado el archivo

Comment: Ok. Voy a añadir una respuesta entonces para que le pueda servir a alguien en el futuro :)

Comment: @MisaelSánchez si la respuesta del usuario Pikoh te ha servido, te recomiendo [aceptar la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`aa-ER` solo está soportado a partir de Windows 10,asi que esa excepción es lanzada al tratar de instalar una solución que haga referencia a dicha cultura en un sistema operativo anterior.

La solución es eliminar toda referencia a la cultura problemática, normalmente suele ser un archivo de recursos con la localización incompatible. En este caso,busca y elimina los archivos que tengan como extensión `.aa-ER.resx`